# Get nested DIV's classes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="star" class="star1">
<div id="star" class="star2">
<div id="star" class="star3">
<div id="star" class="star4">
<div id="star" class="star5">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#star').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(class_name);
});

});
```

The problem I'm having is I'm only ever getting the class of the first parent div.
I want get the class from whichever div is being clicked on. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: you can't give all `<div>` the same `id`

Comment: I think you have to change "id" with "class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ids` of html element should be unique. Assign unique ids and use class selector and assign `common` class to group them.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3k3t/1/)**

```
<div id="star1" class="star">1
<div id="star2" class="star">2
<div id="star3" class="star">3
<div id="star4" class="star">4
<div id="star4" class="star">5
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>​

$('.star').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

The `approach you are using is not correct but` some time you are bound to use such false patterns if it is so you can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LuLQ9/1/)**

```
$('[id=star]').click(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(class_name);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be trying to find a unique identifier for each div. If that is what you are trying to do then you can switch the values of the class attribute with those of the id attribute.

**HTML**

```
<div id="star1" class="star">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.star').click(function(e){

        e.stopPropagation();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });

});
```

In HTML the IDs of elements are meant to be unique whereas the class attribute can be used for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all bear this in mind, **you do not use the same id for multiple tags**.

```
<div id="star1" class="star">1
    <div id="star2" class="star">2
        <div id="star3" class="star">3
            <div id="star4" class="star">4
                <div id="star5" class="star">5
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 jQuery(function($){
$('.star').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#out').html("My Class: "+$(this).attr('class')+ " My Id:" + $(this).attr('id'));
    });​
});
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/RBDZt/1/) , this might be something you are looking for